# Relative positioning of two divs

Tags: css, html, css-position

I made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wSAJ/225/), I am expecting the red div to be positioned directly below the yellow one. They are not. How can I position both the div `up` and `down` relative to `wrapper`?

Guessing it should be simple, but I can't get it to work. **I think I need to use relative**. The 'bars' are time lines and 'float around' freely.

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="background:blue">
    <div class="up" style="background:yellow"/>
    <div class="down" style="background:red"/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.wrapper {
    width:50px;
    height:400px;
    background:blue;
    margin:1em;
}
.up {
    position:relative;
    top:100px;  /*I want this one 100px from the top of .wrapper*/
    height:100px;
}
.down {
    position:relative;
    top:200px;  /*I want this one 200px from the top of .wrapper*/
    height:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`position:relative` relates to the previous `div`.

Div **.up** has height 100px, so to place **.down** directly below .up, .down should contain `top:100px`. Therefore, `top:200px` on .down will place it 200px below .up, which is not what you want as .up only has height 100px. Solve it by changing `top` attribute of .down to `top:100px`

If you want to position it relative to wraper, use `position:absolute`.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/6wSAJ/274

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation, but I need to know if this is possible the way I hoped it to work. The divs are 'time lines', which need to 'float around', so calculating relative to the wrapper is much easier.

Comment: position:absolute actually calculates relative to the wrapper. Is there any reason why you want to use position:relative?

Comment: @WeeYou How would you solve this? http://jsfiddle.net/6wSAJ/463/ those 2 lines bot I have some data in table and I want to show some progress inside by these divs, but I need exact positioning. The relative goes right of the left div and when `position:absolute;` it positions to the whole tr I guess... :(

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to set top:xx; if you want just to stack yellow and red 
modify your html to be in format '<div></div>'  rather than '<div />'