# Relative position in one div for more elements

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a table with some data but I want to use one cell for displaying more divs. Each of divs has different exact width and position from the left.

I tried it with `position:relative` but position of each next div depends on the divs on the left and I don't want that I want each div in that cell to be exactly **x** pixels from left of the cell border.

I also tried `position:absolute` but this does go really to the `<html>` tag as they write here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp:

> An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first
>   parent element that has a position other than static. If no such
>   element is found, the containing block is `<html>`

Now I'm not sure how to solve my problem.

**My example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6wSAJ/465/

(Made from accepted answer from here: [Relative positioning of two divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567610/relative-positioning-of-two-divs))

**Edit:** I guess I forgot to mention that I need it to work in **IE8**.

**Edit 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/6wSAJ/468/ The problem I was dealing with is that if I set the cell relative it completely ruins my real problem table so I have to make divs with relative position around the divs I want to be positioned absolutely. I didn't do that at first cause I always want to try to style the elements I have and add new ones only if really necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the wrapping divs a relative position so the absolute position will apply on inner elements:

```
position: relative;
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6wSAJ/466/)

Note that you can't give a *table-cell* a *relative position* for it's not standardized and will work unexpectedly.

---

For further reading:

- [position - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)
- [Learn CSS Positioning in Ten Steps](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Comment: Well, I actually tried this on my real problem, but it still won't do exactly what I want..  and again it's not working the same way in IE8 as in FF... hate these issues between browsers.

Comment: @Ms.Nobody I've just checked it and it looks the exact same on those two browsers

Comment: Ok, I guess I have to paste the real problem somehow, cause this simple example I was showing my problem on is working ofcourse. But I have more cells there more styling etc - gets more shitty and doesn't work the right way..

Comment: I would like to I just need to reduce the amount of data.. so like in 10 mins it will be there...

Comment: Or actually I might see the problem.. So it really has to be a div who has the position relative? Can't set it on the `<td>` in a way that wouldn't go retarded. :D

Comment: @ms. Nobody Table cells aren't supposed to be given a relationship poistion.  That is why you should Give this poistion to a div

Comment: Yeah, I just did .. it's just I have like 14 td cells in which I want to have these elements with fixed position - that means I have to add 14 relative divs inside them as wrappers, that means extra divs - I just don't like extra divs :D But guess I can't choose other way here. Thx anyway. If you can write in the answer something about that it has to be div not the td that will be relative position I will accept.

Comment: @Ms. Nobody Edited. You should also consider stop using tables for designing.

Comment: Ehm, I'm not using table for designing actually. I'm using it for displaying data and their time flow. I actually know how to design and I don't use tables for that.. I'm not that retarded like ppl from 2000 :D..